Need some help with TikZ shadings
I need some help to get the shading right on a template I am using for special chapters. I need to get the ribbon shading similar to the image below (color doesn't really matter, but the fading from darker to lighter, must come close). At present I am using an image background and just overlay the Chapter number. I am looking for a macro similar to the one below, but can produce better shadings.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {fadings,patterns}
\begin{document}
\NewDocumentCommand\makeribbon{mm}
{ \begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill [black!20] (0,0) rectangle (#1,#2);
  \path [pattern=checkerboard,pattern color=black!30] (0,0) rectangle (#1,#2);
  \shade [ball color=red,path fading=south] (0,0) rectangle (#1,#2);
  \node at (2,1){\bfseries\sffamily\color{black} CHAPTER CONCEPTS};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\makeribbon{6}{3.5}
\end{document}



Are you looking for something like \shade [top color=black,bottom color=red] (0,0) rectangle (#1,#2);? Or what do you mean by "better"?

Yes, but it must look a bit like an air-brushed color (see the difference between the left and the right), i.e., look a bit artistic.

So you want a red rectangle AND a grey wedge shifted in x-direction AND some opacity? // Wrt. graphic design Tikz has its limitations. Perhaps including some prepared graphics where you "print" your text over it is a better approach?

@MS-SPO That is what I have done at present, but the advantage of a TikZ solution is that different colors can be used, so making the template more general.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[blend mode=screen]
\shade[bottom color=red!90!black, top color=black] (0,0) rectangle (19,4);
\shade[left color=red!90!black, right color=black] (0,0) rectangle (1,4);
\end{scope}
\shade[bottom color=white, top color=black!80] (19,0) rectangle (20,4);
\node[lightgray, font=\bfseries\sffamily, yscale=2.5] at (16,0.6) {CHAPTER CONCEPT};
\node[lightgray, font=\bfseries\sffamily\Huge] at (1,1) {8};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Nice effect + 1
